# Rename multiple files in folder with different pattern file name

Tags: batch-rename

I have 7000 folders and each folders have different pattern like this :

**folder 1:**

```
111070290_10_daftar_tabel.pdf
111070290_11_daftar_istilah.pdf
111070290_12_bab_1.pdf
111070290_13_bab_2.pdf
111070290_14_bab_3.pdf
111070290_15_bab_4.pdf
111070290_16_bab_5.pdf
111070290_17_daftar_pustaka.pdf
111070290_18_lampiran.pdf
111070290_1_cover.pdf
111070290_2_lembar_pernyataan_orisinalitas.pdf
111070290_3_lembar_pengesahan.pdf
111070290_4_abstrak.pdf
111070290_5_abstract.pdf
111070290_6_lembar_persembahan.pdf
111070290_7_kata_pengantar.pdf
111070290_8_daftar_isi.pdf
111070290_9_daftar_gambar.pdf
```

**folder 2:**

```
111070117_1_cover.pdf
111070117_2_lembar_pernyataan_orisinalitas.pdf
111070117_3_lembar_pengesahan.pdf
111070117_4_abstrak.pdf
111070117_5_abstract.pdf
```

There are a files i have to rename like example **111070117_3_pernyataan_orisinalitas.pdf** to **111070117_disclaimer.pdf**,etc.

But unfortunately file **XXXXXXXXX_3_pernyataan_orisinalitas.pdf** isn't always **3**. Sometimes it can be **5** or **3** or anything else. I think it would be easier if all files names has the same number after the underline. So I think to catch my destiny should be done in 2 steps.

1. rename **111070117_3_pernyataan_orisinalitas.pdf** to **111070117_pernyataan_orisinalitas.pdf** from all folders.
2. rename **111070117_pernyataan_orisinalitas.pdf** to **111070117_disclaimer.pdf**.

Now i'm stuck in step 1, i need to remove a number after the underline. Any suggestion please?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to use this *rename* perl script: http://www.cyberciti.biz/files/perl/rename.pl.txt
Download it then run via perl, like this:

```
perl /path/to/rename.pl 's/([0-9]{9})_[0-9]_pernyataan_orisinalitas/$1_disclaimer/' *.pdf
```

Here is a working example with multiple folders.
Before:

```
$ ls folder*
folder1:
111070117_3_pernyataan_orisinalitas.pdf

folder2:
111040117_7_pernyataan_orisinalitas.pdf
```

Command:

```
$ perl rename.pl 's/([0-9]{9})_[0-9]_pernyataan_orisinalitas/$1_disclaimer/' folder*/*.pdf
```

After:

```
$ ls folder*
folder1:
111070117_disclaimer.pdf

folder2:
111040117_disclaimer.pdf
```

Of course, I suppose you have perl installed.